# Differentiating between stack and heap memory

Tags: c, free, calloc

Let's say I have a list implementation that uses following `listnode_t`:

```
typedef struct ListNode {
    struct ListNode *next;
    struct ListNode *prev;
    void *value;
} listnode_t;
```

This is a doubly-linked list as you can see. I also have a `list_t`that have two pointer to `listnode_t` as first and last node and size of the list.
Now asume I have following in my main

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    ...
    // Create two empty lists
    list_t *list1 = make_list();
    list_t *list2 = make_list();

    // Populate one with ints
    int x = 4; 
    int y = 5;
    list_push(list1, &x);
    list_push(list1, &y);

    // Populate other with strings
    string_t *str1 = make_string("foo");
    string_t *str2 = make_string("bar");
    list_push(list2, str1);
    list_push(list2, str2);
    ...

    // Delete at the end
    destroy_list(list1);
    destroy_list(list2);
}
```

I have a problem with implementing `destroy_list`. Here is what I tried;

```
void destroy_list(list_t *list)
{
    listnode_t *cur = list -> first;
    for(cur = list -> first; cur != NULL; cur = cur -> next){
        if(cur -> prev){
            free(cur -> prev);
        }
    }

    free(list -> last);
    free(list);
    list = NULL;
}
```

My problem is that, I am trying to use `void *` in the `listnode_t` to be able to use this list generically. But when I delete things, applying `free(cur -> prev)` seems  problematic. When I use a list of things like ints as above, since those are allocated on stack, things are going fine, I guess. But if I had list of strings as above, since I use dynamic allocation in my string implementation I have to apply `free(cur -> prev -> value)` first. I don't know how can I do this because if I add it, then I am getting another problem of trying to free a stack allocated memory on main.

What should I do, I don't get this generic list behaviour.

Comment: The user must provide a function to destroy `value`, as only the user of the list knows what is stored and what needs to be done. So `make_list` must taks as a parameter the function to destroy the value.

Comment: Protip: never ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever use a linked list. Linked list belong in college campus walls, nowhere else.

Comment: What is the definition of list_t?

Comment: If you want to be generic, your list will need to be provided a function pointer to use as a deallocator.

Comment: @Sanchke Dellowar, linked lists are very, very, very useful. Only processing intensity in a certail situation could dictate other data structures and algorithms.

Comment: @SanchkeDellowar saying never to use a container is wrong. Linked lists have their uses, as inefficient as they may be compared to a vector in many cases.

Comment: @SanchkeDellowar that is a very sweeping statement.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie But what would I pass as a deallocator if it is a value like int?

Comment: There is no portable way to detect the difference between stack and heap memory.  You're best off avoiding the issue.  Look at the interface for `qsort()` — and replace the comparator with a deallocator (or add the deallocator)

Comment: @meguli: You could pass: `void free_stack_int(void *vp) { (void)vp; }` which is a do-nothing function — that `(void)vp;` stops the argument from being treated as unused.  You can take the deallocator as an argument to `make_list()`.  That assumes that you have only homogenous lists, but you need a lot more framework to handle heterogeneous lists.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Isn't this insanely ugly? Do people go for generic containers in C or is rolling your own containers for each task is the idiomatic way to program in C?

Comment: @meguli C is not known for it's extreme elegance :)

Comment: Yes, that's insanely ugly.  But then so is stacking pointers to local integers directly onto a list.  The list depends entirely on the context where those variables were defined.  Normally, a container copies what it needs into the list.  It is the list's job to handle the memory it allocates; it might allocate copies of what it is passed, and then return those copies when items are removed from the list.  You have to decide what memory management you want.  And that probably means different implementations for simple data values vs data values using pointers (pointers being harder).

Comment: @EugeneSh.I can live with ugly if that is the way but I still want to learn which ugly way pro C programmers chose.

Comment: @meguli - `list_push(list1, str2);` -> `list_push(list2, str2);` I assume

Comment: @meguli - just curious... what is the use case for placing local variables into a linked list?

Comment: @4386427 That is just my mistake as I am trying to learn about ways of achieving genericity in C. I know actually that I shouldn't use address to local variables but it slipped me by this night as I was focused on other things.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I agree, certain situations call for different tools. Such as a situation debating to use a chain vs a rope... however in my travels I have learned that the use of a linked list in that situation equates the use of a slinky.

Comment: @4386427 No, my mind has been melting from hours of study and I made a lot of mistakes while asking the question. I am editing as people notify me of them.

Comment: I am freeing list in my `destroy_list` and setting it to `NULL` but should nulling the pointer be the job of the owner of the list pointer? Should it be nulled in main?

Answer (score 4):

```
// Populate one with ints
int x, y = 4, 5;
list_push(list1, &x);
list_push(list1, &y);
```

Don't do this.

The interface you've established for your `list` structure effectively says that "ownership" of the pointer passes to the list when `list_push` is called, and that the pointer will be `free()`d by the list in `destroy_list`. Passing a pointer to a stack variable violates that interface -- if you want to pass an integer in, you need to make a copy for the list to take ownership of.

An alternative interface for the `list` structure might be to pass in a pointer and length to `list_push`, and have that function take a copy of the structure instead of retaining it. Whether this is appropriate will depend on the use case you have in mind for this structure.

(Also, `int x, y = 4, 5` doesn't do what you think it does. You probably mean `int x = 4, y = 5`.)

Answer (score 1):

> int x, y = 4, 5;

I do not think this does what you think it does.

> But when I delete things, applying `cur -> prev` seems problematic.

"problematic" is not a technological term.  Describe exactly what you expected to happen, and exactly what happens instead.

> When I use a list of things like ints as above, since those are allocated on stack, things are going fine, I guess.

No, they are anything but fine.  When you take the address of a variable on the stack you are setting yourself up for great disappointment, because as soon as your function returns, the stack is garbage.

> But if I had list of strings as above, since I use dynamic allocation in my string implementation I have to apply `cur -> prev -> value` first

What do you mean by "apply"?  And what do you mean by "first"?

> I don't know how can I do this because if I add it,

What do you mean by "add"?  What is "it"?  Add it to what?  In technological texts we never use prepositions like "it" and "that".  Spell it out.

> then I am getting another problem of trying to free a stack allocated memory on main.

Again, "problem" does not say much.  In any case, if I am to *guess* what your problem is, the solution is simple: always allocate space for `value`, so that you can always free it.

> ```
>     if(cur -> prev){
>         free(cur -> prev);
>     }
> ```

that's not how you delete nodes from a doubly linked list.  In order to delete node Y from a doubly linked list you have to first unlink node Y, so that the `prev` of node Z points to node X, and the `next` of node X points to node Z, and then you may free node Y.  (After freeing its value.)  And of course you have to always keep in mind that node Y may be the first or the last node in the list, in which case it has no previous or next node, and instead you have to modify either the head or the tail of the list structure itself.

Comment: Edited my source and the source in the question in light of this.

Answer (score 1):

The user must provide a function to destroy `value`, as only the user of the list knows what is stored and what needs to be done.

For your list to be generic, `make_list` must taks as a parameter the function to destroy the value. As a partial example:

```
struct LISTROOT {
    listnode_t list;
    void (*freeitem)(void * value);
 };
 struct LISTROOT myList;

 struct MYTYPE {
     char *buffer;
     int *whatever;
 };
 void myFreeItem(struct MYTYPE *item)
 {
     if (item) {
         if (item->buffer) free(item->buffer);
         ...
         free(item);
     }
  }

 myList.list= make_list(myFreeItem);
```

and in your code:

```
    if(cur -> prev){
        if (myList.freeitem) mylist.freeitem(cur->value);
        free(cur -> prev);
```

Note that the list defines `freeitem` to take a `void *` value and the user's `myFreeItem` takes a pointer to a more complex `struct`. The compiler accepts this and allows you to hide the complexity of whatever is stored in the list.

Comment: Maybe what can I do is that instead of passing a deallocator to my data structure, I can return a pointer to the element I am freeing. This way, remove and delete functions of my list would just update their pointers before returning a pointer to the actual memory to be deleted. Then user of the list structure may delete things however they see fit. But this goes against the principles of abstraction I guess. Would it still work though, even if it is a bad method?

Comment: You can do that. You delete node by node and every delete returns the value-object the node stored. `DestroyList` then can't exist anymore. In stead you have `void *DestroyNode(listnode_t *node)`.

Answer (score 0):

A very common model is for the caller of your interface to specify whether or not things should be freed by the container. ie

```
list_t *list1 = make_list(0); // dont free items
list_t *list1 = make_list(1); // free items
```

and if they say 'please free' then you just call `free` for them. This is simpler that the generic 'here is a free callback' that the caller has to supply (Suggested by another answer)

Comment: Why not provide `free` then s the function to use? Max flexibility.

Comment: But what if the element type is very complex that it needs another stage of freeing? I guess it is best to supply required callback for complex lists.

Comment: in the non trivial case then you need to provide a callback function.

Answer (score 0):

A simple and rather safe solution would be to let the list manage copies of the values passed in. Thereby the list is responsible for both allocating and freeing the memory properly.
See the following code which adapts the `struct ListNode` and the `list_push`-function accordingly. Note that the struct does not contain a pointer to the value any more; it rather stores the value in the variable length member `value[]` and allocates enough memory for the struct itself. Hence, freeing the struct object later on will automatically free the memory for the value`s copy, too.

```
typedef struct ListNode {
    struct ListNode *next;
    struct ListNode *prev;
    char value[];
} listnode_t;

void list_push(list_t *t, void *value, size_t valueSize) {

    listnode_t *newNode = malloc(sizeof(listnode_t) + valueSize);
    memcpy (newNode->value, value, valueSize);

    // ... any code necessary for attaching the new node to the list goes here
}
```

Comment: `char []` supposed to store bytes of the value right?